# Embedding so(n) in su(n)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there any way of embedding $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ into $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ for any $n$ other than picking the antisymmetric matrices of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$? I know that for small $n$ one can use isomorphisms to do this, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do this for a general $n$.

In other words, is there a non-standard way of representing $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ using $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ matrices?

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can embed the groups $SO(n)\hookrightarrow SU(n)$, and also the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{so}(n)\hookrightarrow \mathfrak{su}(n)$ for all $n$. This is a classical case arising in nuclear physics and in the theory of Riemannian symmetric spaces. 
For references see the section *Important subgroups* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group), where $SO(n)\subseteq SU(n)$ is explained (which of course implies $\mathfrak{so}(n)\subseteq \mathfrak{su}(n)$ for all $n$). 
Dynkin has classified all possibilities of embeddings among classical Lie algebras.

Comment: Could you please introduce a reference that explains the embedding of classical Lie algebras in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, and more specifically the result of Dynkin. I am in particular interested in knowing how the roots and fundamental weights are mapped under such an embedding.

Comment: See Dynkin's papers, e.g., [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=5435&option_lang=eng).

Comment: Thanks but that is in Russian and I am unable to read it :) Is there an English version of it?

Comment: @QGravity Yes, there is an English version. Try to search it! Hint: AMS Translations 6 (1957),  111-244.